# codeigniter error logged: "Language file contains no data" for the all files in a folder at the same time

Tags: codeigniter

I am receiving very strange (or maybe not) errors in the log files:

```
ERROR - 2018-12-26 03:09:37 --> Language file contains no data: language/lang1/pages/service4_lang.php
ERROR - 2018-12-26 03:09:37 --> Language file contains no data: language/lang1/pages/service2_lang.php
ERROR - 2018-12-26 03:09:37 --> Language file contains no data: language/lang1/pages/service1_lang.php
ERROR - 2018-12-26 03:09:37 --> Language file contains no data: language/lang1/pages/products_lang.php
ERROR - 2018-12-26 03:09:37 --> Language file contains no data: language/lang1/pages/product8_lang.php
ERROR - 2018-12-26 03:09:37 --> Language file contains no data: language/lang1/pages/product9_lang.php
```

and I have those files in the folder. Further more my language setup works already and I don't have any issues of whatever when browsing my site.

```
$config['language'] = 'lang1';
```

is set. Still those messages appear somehow...

Does anybody know what is the reason for this?  How to resolve, track it?

**UPDATE 1**

I have noticed that it happens in the same second (as you can see) and for all files I have in pages folder. So what can trigger this all at once?
Hm, maybe it comes from a loop...

Comment: checked `$config['language'] = 'en';` in config file  ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this one is so particular. I have just discovered that **$this->lang->load("lang file")** will load files from under language directory but it expect that those files contain array of **$lang** like this:

```
$lang['db_invalid_connection_str'] = 'Unable to determine the database settings based on the connection string you submitted.';
$lang['db_unable_to_connect'] = 'Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.';
$lang['db_unable_to_select'] = 'Unable to select the specified database: %s';
$lang['db_unable_to_create'] = 'Unable to create the specified database: %s';
```

and nothing else!

But what if I decided (as I did) to store complete pages under language folder? Then I should be able to load it easily with **$this->lang->load("lang file")** and display on the page. And only because I don't have any variable **$lang** in those pages it will log error every time page is about to be displayed.

I could easily disable that logged message, but instead I decided to hide it on special conditions and here is my if statement added to Land.php class, load function:

```
  if ($basepath !== $package_path && file_exists($package_path) && filesize ($package_path) > 0) {
    //do not log anything, because those files don't have $lang anyway
  } else {
    log_message('error', 'Language file contains no data: language/' . $idiom . '/' . $langfile);
  }
```

That way I will still load files, but error will be displayed only if file doesn't have anything inside.